# Parsing HTML with requests and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm not sure if I'm approaching this correctly. I'm using requests to make a GET:

```
con = s.get(url)
```

when I call con.content, the whole page is there. But when I pass con into BS:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(con.content)
print(soup.a)
```

I get none. There are lots of  tags in there, not behind any JS, that are preset when i call con.content, but when I try to parse with BS most of the page is not there.

Comment: Are you able to provide the url you are getting?

Comment: Unfortunately not. This is work stuff, working with a VPN. If you're looking for something specific I might be able to provide you with some edited code to look at.

Comment: It would just be helpful to see what you are passing to BS in order to help.

Comment: What does `soup` contain?

Comment: soup is con.content, passed through BS. con.content is a big string containing the response from the GET request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the parser to html5lib

```
pip install html5lib
```

And then,

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(con.content,'html5lib')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `a` tags are probably not on the top level.

```
soup.find_all('a')
```

is probably what you wanted.

In general, I found `lxml` to be more reliable, consistent in the API and faster. Yes, even more reliable - I have repeatedly had documents where BeautifulSoup failed to parse them, but lxml in its robust mode `lxml.html.soupparser` still worked well. And there is the [`lxml.etree`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) API which is really easy to use.

Comment: find_all doesn't return anything either. I'll give lxml a try. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see you're html you're getting I just did this on the hacker news site and it returns all the a tags as expected.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.session()

con = s.get('https://news.ycombinator.com/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(con.text)

links = soup.findAll('a')

for link in links:
    print link
```